# Communication between docker and host

Tags: ros, clock, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

This is with respect to the [q313094](https://answers.ros.org/question/313094/is-clock-being-published/?comment=313100#post-id-313100), I was able to get rid of the `/use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic` error by following the steps given in [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/298602/).

However as mentioned in the answer, I always need to run the subscriber first then start publishing the message. If I start publishing first then subscriber it doesn't work.

Could you please let me know is there a way I can fix this, so that I can subscribe to the message anytime?

**Problem description:** 
I have an application which is running inside the docker (Apollo - autonomous driving platform) which uses ros for message communication, I want to create custom messages in my host system and publish to the apollo platform inside docker. For testing purpose I just published simple message by running `rostopic pub -r 10 /test_topic std_msgs/String "hello...."`. This did not work as I was getting error `/use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic`. This was fixed by `By using --net=host, ROS_IP=127.0.0.1 and ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 and running the subscriber from docker before the publisher from host I got it working.` **But this means subscriber must always run before publisher for my scripts to work.**

Update 1:
@dljubic Please find the details given below:

Outside the docker container:

```
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI - http://localhost:11311
echo $ROS_HOSTNAME   - empty
echo $ROS_IP         - empty
```

Inside the docker container:

```
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI - http://172.17.0.1:11311
echo $ROS_HOSTNAME   - empty
echo $ROS_IP         - 172.17.0.1
```

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318939/communication-between-docker-and-host/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-20**:
Can you summarize the problem and what you're trying to do? This question doesn't stand on its own as is.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-03-20**:
Apologies, I will elaborate the issue. I have updated the question. Thank you.

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2019-03-23**:
Cloud you please provide the output of `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI`, `echo $ROS_HOSTNAME` and `echo $ROS_IP` on your host i.e. outside of a Docker container and inside a Docker container?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-03-25**:
@dljubic I have updated the question with the details (inside and outside docker container). I am not seeing any output for `HOSTNAME and IP` outside the docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello kk2105,

I can share the configuration that always works for me. First, I start `roscore` outside a docker container.
Locally, and in docker container, I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$(hostname --ip-address):11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=$(hostname --ip-address)
```

Caveat: docker container was created with a `--network host` flag.

Please try that configuration and let me know if it helps!

---

Originally posted by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) with karma: 516 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-04-03**:
@dljubic Sorry for the delayed reply. Thanks for the answer. I will try this out and update you here.